# Django Rest Framework does 'serializers.DictFields' no longer exist?

Tags: django, dictionary, django-rest-framework

If I import serializers from below, and look for all the fields, I don't see `DictField`

```
>>> from rest_framework import serializers
>>> print("\n".join([foo for foo in dir(serializers) if "Field" in foo]))
BooleanField
BoundField
CharField
ChoiceField
DateField
DateTimeField
DecimalField
DjangoImageField
EmailField
Field
FieldDoesNotExist
FileField
FloatField
HiddenField
HyperlinkedIdentityField
HyperlinkedRelatedField
ImageField
IntegerField
ListField
ManyRelatedField
ModelField
MultipleChoiceField
NestedBoundField
NullBooleanField
PrimaryKeyRelatedField
ReadOnlyField
RegexField
RelatedField
SerializerMethodField
SkipField
SlugField
SlugRelatedField
StringRelatedField
TimeField
URLField
```

But it's in the docs [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#dictfield), just after ListField (which is in the above list). Has this gone in the latest version of DRF, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DictField was added in [3.0.4](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#30x-series).

UPDATE!