# Django Rest Framework serialize query set into dictionary with custom field

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get this kind of JSON:

```
"Physical": {
            "Strength": 1,
            "Dexterity": 1,
            "Stamina": 1
        },
```

But with my Custom serializer:

```
class EnumField(serializers.Field):

    """
    Enum objects are serialized into " 'label' : value " notation
    """

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {"{0}".format(obj.all()[0].__str__()): obj.all()[0].current_value}



class EnumListField(serializers.DictField):
    child = EnumField()
```

And this on my model:

```
@property
def physical_attributes(self):
    return [self.attributes.filter(attribute=attribute) for attribute
            in AttributeAbility.objects.physical()]
```

Outputs this:

```
 "mental_attributes": [
            {
                "Intelligence": 1
            }, 
            {
                "Wits": 0
            }, 
            {
                "Resolve": 0
            }
        ],
```

What do I need to do to my field, to look like my first JSON? I don't think [DictField](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28498923/1075247) exists anymore, which is what a few questions on SO suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property returns a list, and you want `key:value` pairs, so treat them as a dictionary:

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
    return {str(item.get()): item.get().value for item in obj}
```

Obviously replace `.value` with whatever value you want, and if the `str()` representation is not what you want for the key, replace that.